# Is there any way to generate data dictionary in DOC or Excel format in PHP MyAdmin 4.5.1

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

In PHP MyAdmin 4.5.1 there is a option for generating Data Dictionary of Databages.
[Data Dictionary option Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZUiqD.png)

But I need to generate it with DOC or Excel format. 
Is it possible?

Or is there any other way to manage it?
[image: Data Dictionary output]
This is the output I get when I clicked on Data Dictionary

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it's not possible. You have to manually do it.